# Phone won't connect to flask server on same wifi network

Tags: java, python, networking, deployment, flask

I have a local server running via Flask. I go to localhost:5000 and I get served with my test page.

My computer's IP address on my wifi network is 192.168.1.128. My phone is connected to the same wifi network as my laptop.

When I access 192.168.1.128:5000 on either my laptop or phone, I get served with "This site cannot be reached: 192.168.1.128 refused to connect."

Why is this happening? My firewall is disabled and my httpd.conf seems to allow anything. Here's that file incase I'm missing something: https://gist.github.com/MatthewPageCS/3eee9ac18dc8311302b37946f5eb338a

All I need to do is connect my phone to a server running my flask code. Any idea what could be causing my computer to allow me to connect to localhost but not the wifi IP address?

Comment: Is the flask app listening on `0.0.0.0` or `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: @NehalJ.Wani Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/

Comment: Your app is listening on localhost. It is not listening on all interfaces or the interface via which the packets from your mobile will reach to it. Replace `127.0.0.1` with `0.0.0.0` and the restart the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run your flask application on `0.0.0.0` otherwise it will not be an externally visible server.

Take a loot at the [Flask Quickstart Documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/).